# RPostgreSQL - Nested selects

Tags: sql, r, rpostgresql

I am trying to:

```
dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM test WHERE id in (select fid from test2)")
```

However, I get the error:

```
 RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  column "fid" does not exist
```

Is nested selects not supported by RPostgreSQL?

Comment: Yes, no problems in PgAdmin

Comment: Okay, the problem was that "fid" was with capital letters in the database. So apparently they are converted to small letters when running the dbGetQuery command.